# How to name API route "...admin..." using Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, routes, azure-functions

I'm moving components from Web services to Azure Functions. I'd like to keep my API endpoints unchanged. I have an admin controller which has endpoints like this:

```
/admin/Heartbeat
```

My corresponding implementation looks like this:

```cs
[FunctionName("Heartbeat")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> RunHeartbeat(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "admin/Heartbeat" )] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    ...
}
```

If any of the routes start with "admin", I get this error message:

> The specified route conflicts with one or more built in routes.

There's near no information about this built-in restriction - or I cannot find it. There's a couple of mentions on GitHub ([thread 1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/141), [thread 2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1781)), but no one has a proper solution to this issue.

A workaround is to rename the route - which is exactly what I'd like to avoid.

Is there any solution that allows using "admin" in routes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `admin` in routes is reserved strictly for the azure functions runtime host.

Currently, any routes starting with `admin` have that issue.

Admin API exposed by functions host:

```
GET https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/status
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": "bad1ecf31b47-2137340777",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "2.0.1.0",
  "versionDetails": "2.0.1.0-beta1 Commit hash: N/A"
}
```

More info on this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Admin-API

---

**Workaround**

You can change the route name to `v2/admin/Heartbeat` in function code.

Example:

```cs
[FunctionName("ExampleAdminRoute")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v2/admin/Heartbeat")]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    //your admin function code
}
```

Then, you can add a proxy to the route (more info on azure function proxies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies)). Proxies are stored in `proxies.json`.

Make sure this file is copied to the build output directory i.e. including in .csproj file.

Example `proxies.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "AdminProxy": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": [ "GET" ],
        "route": "/api/admin/Heartbeat"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://localhost/api/v2/admin/Heartbeat"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when you run the functions app, you should see console output like:

```sh
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7071/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...

Http Functions:

    AdminProxy: http://localhost:7071/api/admin/Heartbeat

    ExampleAdminRoute: http://localhost:7071/api/v2/admin/Heartbeat
```

Any requests coming to `api/admin/Heartbeat` will automatically be redirected to `api/v2/admin/Heartbeat`.

Proxies are flexible enough to support different requests (GET/POST) with parameters etc.

Comment: Wow. Thank you, @rithin-chalumuri! I'll give this a go next week.

Comment: I just ran into this issue with our client side angular app. We can't have a module named "admin", so I'll have to name it something else now. The problem exposes itself if you navigate to the admin area of the app, and then refresh the page :( I must have missed this restriction in the docs somewhere.